# Ionic Beta Button Height

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, button, ionic3

I am using the ionic beta and want to write a simple calculator app for learning. My first problem now is that I can't change the height of any buttons:

[image]

The buttons are placed in an `<ion-grid>` element:

```
<ion-content class="mainpage" scroll="false">
<ion-grid>
<ion-row class="result">
  <ion-col><p class="result">0</p></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col width-50><button large round full class="myButton">AC</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round full class="myButton">+/-</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round full class="myButton">/</button></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">7</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">8</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">9</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round full class="myButton">*</button></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">4</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">5</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">6</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round full class="myButton">+</button></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">1</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">2</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round block outline class="myButton">3</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round full class="myButton">-</button></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col width-75><button large round block outlin class="myButton"e>0</button></ion-col>
  <ion-col><button large round full class="myButton">=</button></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

For the rows I set `height: 100%;` manually and it worked but the buttons don't stretch with the same attributes. **I want them to fill the rows height.**

Edit:

Here's the CSS:

```
ion-grid
{
    height: 100%;
}

ion-row
{
    height: 100%;
}

.myButton
{
    height: 100%;
}

.result
{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 42px;
    background-color: #00AFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In the `app.variables.scss` file (below the color definitions) override the Ionic sass variable for button height... `$button-md-large-height: 50px;`

Comment: At the moment the buttons look like this:
http://imgur.com/YPyQaqo
If I change `$button-md-large-height` to `height: 100%;` they look like this:
http://imgur.com/1eAwot1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.. and I noticed that the main.css has .button-ios and .button-md that adjusts the height of the button component.

In my page scss file I did this:

```
.button-ios { #ios css 
    height: auto;
}

.button-md { #android css
    height: auto;
}
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button class='button button-positive large_button'>
 Large button</button>
```

and css:

```
.large_button {
  line-height: 20vh !important;
    width: 50%;
  }
```

Just give it a class, and define line height.

Comment: This was exactly what I found after google research, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your button:

```
<button large round full block class="myButton">AC</button></ion-col>
```

and add a similar code in CSS:

```
.myButton { height:100%; }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I found out that I can't set the buttons height to 100% if the parents height isn't 100%. The direct parent is the `<ion-col>` but if I set the height of the col to 100% it looks pretty weird ... The Buttons are now overlapped and some are out of the screen.

Comment: I understood. In my test I set the ion-col height to 300px.

Comment: But how do you want you want to increase the row height.. I see nothing in your code.

Comment: I want the buttons to fill the height so there are only the specific padding/margin spaces between them.

Comment: try this: .myButton {
    height: 15%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;}

Answer (score 0):

### IONIC 3.x

From HTML template you can create a simple button with:

```
<button ion-button>Default</button>
```

[image]

If you need exactly the "calculator" buttons:

```
<button ion-button style="border-radius: 32px;">Default</button>
```

[image]

If you want the outline style simply you can write:

```
<button ion-button outline style="border-radius: 32px;">Default</button>
```

[image]

You can find more information following the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#outline-buttons).

Answer (score 0):

**IONIC 4.0**

In Ionic 4.0 you have to set shadow DOM variable like so:

```
ion-button { --height: auto; }
```